# Entity Framework accessing db methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm quite new at this so forgive me for not knowing how to word this properly.

I have setup Entity Framework with a rather large database and have been trying to learn how to manipulate tables in the database.

My first method worked but I ran into an error. It would load the data into a datagridview just fine but when sliding the bar over to view the tables not on the screen it would throw an error. This is the process that triggered the error:

```
using (var context = new MydbEntities())
{
    var query = (from a in db.Configurations
                 select a);

    var result = query.ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
}
```

Now if I change the first line to `MydbEntities db = new MydbEntities();` I don't get an error. I'm trying to follow online tutorials but I thought maybe someone could help me understand the difference in these two.

Comment: Could we possibly have the details of the error?

Comment: Does `Configurations` have any related entities?

Comment: Please, reqview your question. What is the `db` in your code sample? Where is it declared? When does the error trigger?

Comment: The error message is huge, basically says the context object has been disposed. Which led me to think that it's trying to query the Configurations table as I scroll to a certain point and it can't because it no longer has access to the table. Configurations is the table it is accessing. db, if memory and terminology serves me correctly is the instantiation of the database object.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you met lazy-load and fact that Context got disposed when you tried to query next batch of records.

You have serveral options here, best ones in my opinion are:

1. Use [EntityDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488502%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). This way DataControl will take care of EF Context instantiation and disposal. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488502(v=vs.100).aspx) has pretty good specs on that).
2. Implement custom [ObjectDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). Use EF context within ObjectDataSource methods, instantiating and disposing it when needed.
   ([This article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control,-part-1-getting-started) on the topic is little outdated, but you still can get the idea).

Comment: What exactly indicates this is the solution? What is the problem uberhaupt?

Comment: Thanks vittore, I thought that's what it might be. Is there a problem with the second way I did it? Basically replacing 'using (var context = new MydbEntities())' with 'MydbEntities db = new MydbEntities();' seems to do away with the error. I just want to make sure that it won't cause other issues.